# Problem booting Ubuntu

Tags: boot, windows-7, wubi

I have installed Ubuntu over a previous Windows 7 installation using wubi.
Once the boot manager asks for which operating system I want I click on Linux, but a message comes up that says:

(Taken from [screenshot](http://postimage.org/image/494mriehb/) from comments).

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware of software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:

1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer
2. Chose your language settings and then click next
3. Click repair your computer.

If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance. 

    File \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr (NB: Not sure about this line, hard to make out)

    Starus: 0xc00000093 (NB, this may be an 8 not a 3)

    Info: The selected entry could not be loaded because the application is missing or corrupt.
```

Comment: You will have to be more specific.

Comment: Error: no boot disk has been detected or disk has failed

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?  That's not something that GRUB says...

Comment: [link](http://postimage.org/image/k0gelyemz/)

Comment: [link](http://postimage.org/image/494mriehb/) I ve just uploaded the tow error that i get

Comment: @GhassarQhassarMohamed Get into your bios when you reboot and change the location where you are trying to boot from. I suspect, its trying to boot out of a location that is not existent.

Comment: I VE TRIED IT its still the same

Answer (score 0):

It seems wubi bootloader file is missing or corrupted.

You can restore wubi bootloader using [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20340/how-to-restore-the-wubi-ubuntu-bootloader/).